# Firestore Function - Run on Dynamic Schedule

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

There is a way to [schedule firebase functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/schedule-functions) to run at a specified time.

I want to schedule a function to run at a time specified in a firestore database. If the time changes in the database, the function should update and run according to that new time. Is this possible?

Comment: Solution is too long for Stack Overflow, but you can read here: https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-schedule-a-cloud-function-to-run-in-the-future-in-order-to-build-a-firestore-document-ttl-754f9bf3214a

Comment: This is promising! It definitely feels a bit hacky, but I can see it working. Thanks for the resource.